In Clean Architecture, why is the String component stated to have an I metric of 1?
Stability (or instability) is measured as I = fan-out / (fan-in + fan-out), so why is the String component stated to have an I of 1? Don’t far more classes depend on String compared to the classes that String depends on, so wouldn’t I = 0? What am I missing here?
